# My windows slave is running as unix slave in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

it is weird that jenkins no recognizing slave as windows. it is launched as JAVA WEBSTART but it runs as unix slave. How can i have this run as windows slave?

```
JNLP agent connected from /198.112.40.148
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Slave.jar version: 2.21
This is a Unix slave
WARNING: C:\softs\jenkins looks suspiciously like Windows path. Maybe you meant C:/softs/jenkins?
Copied maven-agent.jar
Copied maven3-agent.jar
Copied maven3-interceptor.jar
Copied maven-interceptor.jar
Copied maven2.1-interceptor.jar
Copied plexus-classworld.jar
Copied classworlds.jar
Slave successfully connected and online
```

Comment: What is the jenkins version?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins tries to [guess the OS](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/be403d3781ba61a7bfb74e20f7e3534c30a5c9be/core/src/main/java/hudson/slaves/SlaveComputer.java) based on parth.separator. For some reason your java process has it set wrongly.

Are you over-riding the path.separator property in your command line?

Answer (score 0):

If cygwin is involved with this, then perhaps you are connecting to a Unix-ish environment on top of Windows.